# Create class diagram with doxygen

Tags: class, doxygen, class-diagram, doxygen-wizard

I'm using Doxygen to create a class documentation from my code, which is written in `C++`. I want to create a UML for the whole code in a single graph? Is it possible? Because Doxygen is trying to create a UML for each class but the thing I'm trying to create is to create a big graph for the entire code. Any idea or suggestion is appreciated. BTW I use doxywizard for generating the class diagrams and documentations.

Comment: With doxygen this is currently not possible.

Comment: @albert Is it possible with another software or it is not possible at all?

Comment: Might be possible with other software, but I'm not aware of anything.